# DefaultClientSideWebParts properties documentation

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Do you have any idea where I can find documentation to those builtin webparts,
I must create them programmatically with powershell so I need properties names,
I already search through google but without any good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any good documentation for the web-part properties in the past. If you need to add the parts to modern SharePoint pages I would recommend using:

```
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page $homePage -Component "b519c4f1-5cf7-4586-a678-2f1c62cc175a" -Section 1 -Column 1
```

You can find the ID by adding the WebPart to another page and looking for the ID in dev tools. The ID name is data-sp-feature-instance-id.

Comment: That solve my problem :), but I hope that somewhere such docs exist